# conditionally link to images from twitter in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter

Right now I'm trying to grab the URL of images of tweets, but only if the tweet contains an image.I'm successfully able to pull tweets and pull some images, but if the tweet doesn't have an image, it breaks and stops displaying tweets.

tweets.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of tweetsdata">
  <div class="profile-pic><img  src={{item.user.profile_image_url}}>
  </div>

  <div class="screenname">{{item.user.name}}</div>

  <div class="tweet-content">{{item.text}}</div> <!-- correctly pulls in all tweets -->

 <div class="tweet-img">
    <img src="{{item.entities.media[0].media_url}}" /> <!-- breaks when post doesn't have a photo, no more tweets load after it -->
</div>

</div>
```

I tried setting the source as a string in the .ts file and conditionally changing the value of the string if it returned null like this:

```
<p>{{item.entities.media[0].media_url != null ? item.entities.media[0].media_url : 'hello'}}</p>
```

But I don't think it would work because I'm pulling from the JSON, and wouldn't want to reassign anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check to insert the div to DOM with *ngIf before assigning image to src attribute

```
<div *ngFor="let item of tweetsdata">
  <div class="profile-pic><img  src={{item.user.profile_image_url}}>
  </div>

  <div class="screenname">{{item.user.name}}</div>

  <div class="tweet-content">{{item.text}}</div> 
 <div class="tweet-img" *ngIf="item.entities.media[0].media_url">
    <img src="{{item.entities.media[0].media_url}}" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, while the logic makes sense, this solution didn't work for me. I still keep getting the error: 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' whenever a tweet doesn't have an image, but now, tweets with images also don't print out either. Is there an ngIf statement the equivalent of saying if it's null, don't even create the image tag?

Comment: can you create a plunker solution for your issue. Will help you solve it. You can stub the data for now , but try to reproduce the exact issue in plunker.