# Angular4- Displaying item in JSON that isn't always present in

Tags: javascript, json, angular, twitter

Still building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995161/angular4-how-to-check-if-twitter-media-key-exists-or-is-undefined/45995200#45995200), to pull in media data from the tweet JSON that I've made a call to. At first, I thought it would be as simple as iterating through the JSON, but the entities.media.media_url are not always present, and will return undefined errors for the tweets that don't contain them. I tried creating a method that would pull the data if it exists, but I'm not able to get it to iterate.

tweets.component.html

```
    <div class="tweet-container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of tweetsdata" class="tweets-card">
      <div class="tweet-text">
        <p class="tweet-date">{{item.created_at | slice:0:10}}</p>
        <p>{{item.text}}</p>
        <!-- <img src={{getImage()}}> -->
           <!-- <p>hello: {{item.entities?.media[0].media_url}}</p> -->

           <p>{{getImage()}}</p>

        <div class="interact-tweet">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={{item.id_str}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id={{item.id_str}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/like?tweet_id={{item.id_str}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

tweets.component.ts

```
...
searchcall() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    // const searchterm = 'query=' + this.searchquery;
    const searchterm = 'query=from%3Adailymuse%20%23' + this.searchquery;


    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post('https://localhost:3000/search', searchterm, {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      this.tweetsdata = [
        res.json().data.statuses[0],
        res.json().data.statuses[1],
        res.json().data.statuses[2],
        res.json().data.statuses[3],
        res.json().data.statuses[4]
      ];

      console.log(this.tweetsdata);
      this.screen_name = this.tweetsdata[0].user.screen_name;
      this.user = this.tweetsdata[0].user.name;
      this.profile_img_url = this.tweetsdata[0].user.profile_image_url_https;
      this.user_id = this.tweetsdata[0].user.id_str;
    });
  }

  getImage() {

    if (this.tweetsdata.entities) // will keep returning undefined because it's not pointing to a specific tweet in the array, tweetsdata
      {
      const imgURL = this.tweetsdata.entities.media[0].media_url;
      console.log(imgURL);
      return  imgURL;
      } else {
        console.log('nope');
      }
    }
```

I think *ngIf would make the most sense to use, but I'm unsure how to set up the statement to check if the key exists first, then present the link. This is what I've tried:

```
<p *ngIf="item.entities">{{item.entities.media[0].media_url}}</p>
```

Which technically works if there is an attached image present, but it breaks the code for the following tweets that don't contain an image. Am I setting up the if statement correctly?

Comment: did you try to check for null? like : `item.entities != null` ?

Comment: @MrMisery thanks! I actually had to check if it was undefined (`*ngIf="item.extended_entities != undefined"`), but that logic worked!